# Getting error when using "not in" in command text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an EntityDataSource in which command text contains not in.

The queries looks like :-

```
SELECT  User.LastName,  User.Suffix  
FROM    [User]
WHERE  [User].UserId not in (select [Contractors].UserId from Contractors)
```

This results in following error:-

```
The element type 'Edm.Guid' and the CollectionType 'Transient.collection[Transient.rowtype[(UserId ,Edm.Guid(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=))](Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]' are not compatible. The IN expression only supports entity, primitive, and reference types.
```

Any ideas how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

That is because you cannot use a IN clausule with Guid (unique identifier) types. Your UserId is of unique identifier type, so use another way to check that without an IN, like a temporary table, etc.

Try with a left join with the Tables, research more about SQL, here is an example:

```
SELECT  User.LastName,  User.Suffix  
FROM    [User]
Left Join [Contractors] on [User].UserId = [Contractors].UserId
WHERE [Contractors].UserId IS NULL
```

I'm not sure if that is gonna work, I cannot test it right now.
I'm sure there is a better way to do what I am doing, but that was the error that you were having....

Comment: can you please guide me on how to fix this as I cannot find a way to do this.